# Does setkey() work retrospectively? (in R)

Tags: r, data.table

Consider data frame df1, which is set as data table. Notice that a key is not set.

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(v1 = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 4 )])
setDT(df1)
tables()  #  verify that df1 is now data table. No key.
     NAME NROW NCOL MB COLS KEY
[1,] df1     4    1  1 v1      
Total: 1MB

df2 <- df1  #  create df2 as copy of df1

tables()
     NAME NROW NCOL MB COLS KEY
[1,] df1     4    1  1 v1      
[2,] df2     4    1  1 v1      #  two data tables. No keys.
Total: 2MB

setkey(df2, v1)  #  set key to df2 (only)

tables()
     NAME NROW NCOL MB COLS KEY
[1,] df1     4    1  1 v1   v1  #  both df1 and df2 are assigned keys 
[2,] df2     4    1  1 v1   v1  #  it is as if df1 is assigned key via df2 ('retrospectively')
Total: 2MB
```

However, if I made a change to df2, say adding a column, before setting the key, the behavior of setkey() would be different: would NOT be "retrospective". (See code below).
I was wondering why this is the case. Thanks

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(v1 = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 4 )])
setDT(df1)
tables()
     NAME NROW NCOL MB COLS KEY
[1,] df1     4    1  1 v1      
Total: 1MB
df2 <- df1
tables()
     NAME NROW NCOL MB COLS KEY
[1,] df1     4    1  1 v1      
[2,] df2     4    1  1 v1      
Total: 2MB

df2$v2 <- c(1:4) # add column, therefore v2 != v1

setkey(df2, v1)

tables()
     NAME NROW NCOL MB COLS  KEY
[1,] df1     4    1  1 v1         #  in this instance v1 wasn't set a key via df2
[2,] df2     4    2  1 v1,v2 v1 
Total: 2MB
```

Comment: You need to use `copy` here as in `df2 <- copy(df1)`. This is a known behaviour in `data.table`

Comment: `df2 <- df1` does NOT create *a copy* of `df1` in `df2`. R performs *copy-on-write* (or *copy-on-modify*).